# What is the location of redis.conf in official docker image?

Tags: docker, redis, dockerfile

I know that it is possible to pass your own config file but I'd rather edit the handful of values I care about in the default config. I'm having a hard time finding a default redis.conf anywhere though, do I just have to COPY my own into the container?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The default image from redis does not have a redis.conf.

Here is the link for the image on dockerhub. https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/

You will have to copy it to image or have it mapped on the host using a volume mapping.

Comment: What folder should the `redis.conf` get copied to, in the case of using a custom config?

Comment: @grizzthedj in order to use custom config you need to copy to /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf

Comment: If you need access to the configuration of a running Redis instance, I suggest to log into the container. Then run `redis-cli` and execute `CONFIG GET *`. See: https://redis.io/commands/config-get

Comment: Use this command => redis-cli CONFIG GET "*"

Answer (score 4):

You can get the example redis config file from [github](https://github.com/redis/redis). It just located at root path. Note that select the branch match your version.

Then you can custom the config file base on the example config file above. Then run the command `docker run -v /path/to/your/custom/config/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf`.

Comment: this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The below steps worked for me

1. go to Redis website and download the version you are using
   https://redis.io/download/
   after unzipping, there is redis.conf file  modify  it
2. daemonize no
3. bind 0.0.0.0   (Comment original put this )
4. set your password
   requirepass 1782dc476064567822
5. start container
   docker run --name redis --net redis -p 6379:6379 -v /opt/redis/config:/home/redis -v /opt/redis/data:/data/ -d  redis:7.0.8-alpine redis-server /home/redis/redis.conf

Answer (score 1):

docker image has not config file.

"Redis is able to start without a configuration file using a built-in default configuration, however this setup is only recommended for testing and development purposes."

you can download a config file, according your version, here:
https://redis.io/docs/management/config/

And you can set it like this:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis:7.2.3
COPY config/redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  redis:
    image: my-redis:7.2.3
    container_name: redis
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/data
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if the docker is running then you can use the following command to get all the details of docker location, images, containers etc.

docker info

Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 40
 Goroutines: 150

you can also use docker -v to get the version details

Comment: I can't find out relation of your response with this question !??!